# How can I make a header file appear on every new project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, code-templates

I'm very new to programming so hopefully I don't sound too dumb. I'm using visual studios to learn on and reading Bjarne Stroustrup's book "Programming Principles and Practice Using C++" and the book uses a header file called "std_lib_facilities.h" for every example. I've been copying the file into every single program manually and its getting kind of tedious. Is there any way to setup visual studios to were when I create a new project the header file will just automatically be there?

Comment: I suggest losing the habit of using `std:lib_facilities.h`. Instead, learn to look up the functions/types you are using from the standard library, and include only the headers needed. For example, if your code uses `std::string`, reads from `std::cin`, and writes to `std::cout`,  you only need to use `<string`>` and `<iostream>` - not most of the C++ standard library. Apart from easing typing, the more enduring cost of using headers like `std_lib_facitities.h` is compilation times - which may not seem much in toy projects, but can mean a lot of lost time with building non-trivial projects.

Comment: I wonder why a book from Bjarne is promoting something the equivalent of the infamous `<bits/stdc++.h>`. Programmers need to know the headers.

Comment: The main reason Bjarne uses a header like that is to ease the writing of a book (not having to duplicate explanations of header files for every code sample).   However, it is considered very BAD practice in the real world of development - and will bite as soon as you start developing larger programs that need to be organised across multiple source files.      From memory (I haven't read that book in a long time) he states that when he first introduces that header, but a beginner will gloss over the point that it is for the book, not how they should do things.

Comment: I'm still in the beginning of the book so I don't know how much he uses it, the only thing that the book actually uses from it is a small function called "keep_window_open", which literally just waits for a character input followed by enter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, There is a way to add automatically the additional libraries and header files into every project you create.

Navigate the window into MSBulid\v4.0 by using the below command in run window

%localappdata%\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0

Then you can find the Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.User.props

Right click the Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.User.props  and open with notepad or notepad++

```
<ImportGroup Label="Property sheets"/>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <IncludePath> header file path </IncludePath>
    <LibraryPath> library Path </LibraryPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Add the above code in Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.User.props inside  tag.
And save the Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.User.props

Open the Visual Code in Admin

Have a nice day :)